# Write value from csv to xlsx file based on matching name using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two files one an xlsx file and the other a csv file. I need to take the Fantasy points from the csv file and write them to the xlxs file IF the two names match above a 50% ratio.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/aus10/Desktop/PGA/Tournament_Results/A_Military_Tribute_at_the_Greenbrier_2020.xlsx')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/aus10/Desktop/PGA/Fantasy_Tournament_Results/Greenbrier_2020.csv')

for name in df['Player_Name']:
    for second_name in df_2['Name']:
        Ratio = Ratio = fuzz.ratio(name.lower(),second_name.lower())
        if Ratio >= 50:
            df.at[-1, 'FPTS'] = df_2['FantasyPointsDraftKings']
```

I'm not exactly sure how to tell it to write to that specific file when the names match but here's what I have

I want to use the name from the bottom `xlsx` file and if it matches the name from the `csv` file then I want to take the `FantasyPointsDraftKings` value from that name and write it to the `xlxs` file matching the names and adding the value to `FPTS` Column in the `xlsx` file.

[image]
[image: xlsx file]

Google Sheets link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jfr4Ma86dfLS5VnoCXTbNOJtDXxsG7HK5lt3meteEXI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Put sample data of the 2 files as text not as image

Comment: @bigbounty I linked a google sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you have to read the 2 files into pandas dataframe
2. Take a subset of relevant columns of the 2 dataframes
3. write a function that takes the above columns (point 2) and calculates the similarity

Here I have used Jaro-Wrinkler distance to find the similarity - [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%20and%20statistics,Jaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%20and%20statistics,Jaro)).

You can use a different algorithm for matching

```
    import pandas as pd
    import jellyfish
    
    csv = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
    excel = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
    
    def process(row):
        match = jellyfish.jaro_distance(row["Name"], row["Player_Name"])
        if match > 0.5: return row["FantasyPoints"]
        return None
    
    excel["FantasyPoints"] = pd.concat([csv["Name"],csv["FantasyPoints"],excel["Player_Name"]],axis=1).apply(process, axis=1)
    
    excel.to_excel("data.xlsx")
```

Output:

```
       Player_Name  Scrambling  Average_Driving_Distance  Fairways_Hit    GIR  Sand_Saves  Average_Putts_GIR  Total_Putts_GIR  Putts_Per_Round  SG_Putting  SG_Around_the_Green  SG_Approach_the_Green  SG_Off_the_Tee   FPTS  FantasyPoints
0  Joaquin Niemann       78.57                     313.0         64.29  80.56       83.33              1.603               93            27.50        2.20                 0.56                   1.13            0.51  142.5          142.5
1         Tom Hoge       78.57                     315.1         67.86  61.11       71.43              1.591               70            25.25        0.69                 0.74                   0.89            0.57  113.0          113.0
2     Brian Harman       83.33                     303.1         64.29  66.67       40.00              1.646               79            26.00        1.27                 0.10                   0.72            0.56  107.5          107.5
```